# Vertical centering element inside adaptive-height div and hide overflow parts

Tags: css, overflow, vertical-alignment, hidden

I have a container `div` which contains an element with fixed proportions (an image for simplicity, but can be a video too). From now, I'll identify the `container` div with container and the element inside it with `element`.

**Requirements**

Here's what I'm trying to get (possibly using **CSS only**, without JS)

1. `container` must be 100% of window width and 50% of window height (see height exception in requirement n.5)
2. `element` must fill 100% of `container` width and keep its proportions (don't have to be deformed from window resizes)
3. `element` must be centered both vertically and horizontally inside `container`
4. when `element` height is higher than `container` height, excess parts of `element` above and below `container` must be hidden
5. when `element` height is lower than `container` height, container height must fit `element` height

The goal is to essentially create something equivalent to what `background-size:cover` does with images, but applied to a generic element with fixed proportions.

**My (partial) solution**

Here's my actual code. I've managed to achieve requirements n.1,2,4 (see [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7cxb4082/1/)) but I'm still struggling to find a solution for 3 and 5. In the posted fiddle I've commented `overflow:hidden` property and set a border to container to better show my goal.

```
.container {
    margin-top:100px;
    border:2px solid red;
    height:50vh;
    display:block;
    /*overflow:hidden;*/
    position:relative;
}

.container>* {
    position:absolute;
    top:-25vh;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How about using `max-width:100%;` and `max-height:100%;`?

Comment: @jackweinbender do you mean for `element` style?

Comment: Yes. Though, on second thought, I guess you would want to keep `width:100%;` and just include `min-height:100%;`. Obviously, this doesn't fix the vertical centering issue, but it's a start.

Comment: @jackweinbender I've tried adding `min-height:100%` to element, but it didn't work. Here's the resulting fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7cxb4082/5/ Thanks anyway.

Comment: I can get you everything but step #5... I'm thinking it's not possible with solely CSS.

Comment: @Chad in this case, I may consider JS solutions too (my requirement on CSS was only a preference).

Comment: How about this (pretty close): http://jsfiddle.net/1aLcqokf/

Comment: @Giorgio jQuery or vanilla?

Comment: @jackweinbender: it's good when `element` height is higher than `container` height, but it deforms image when window width becomes small (fails on requirement n.2).

Comment: @Chad Jquery if possible. Thanks.

Comment: @Giorgio this is a decently simple solution to that using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/7cxb4082/7/ Granted, you'd have to throw some resize calculations in there, but that's the gist of it.